# Calling source with RLink in Mathematica

Tags: rlink

Let's imagine that I have a file called gensys.R where a function gensys is defined, which I would like to use in the mathematica environment and work with it.

When using RLink, I've tried

```
REvaluate[
 "source(" path\gensys.R ")"]
```

However, I receive an error message when I run the command, related to the double use of the " sign...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to escape quotation marks in a string with "\"". The same hold true for backslashes (you need "\\"). So try this: `REvaluate["source(\"path\\gensys.R\")"]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the comment. However, now I get Java(TM) Plataform SE binary critical error...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Is there a pdf user guide which I can learn about using RLink. The documentation on the wolfram site seems to be lacking... maybe it's some inattention on my part.

Comment: That's something you should ask @Szabolcs.

Comment: The right one to ask would be @LeonidShifrin, as was working on this. Have you ensured, that your path is indeed correctly escaped and exists? It seems odd, that such a simple call should crash the JRE.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the comment by Henrik was helpful in reaching the right answer. In R, the sign we should use is / not \ nor double \.

So, the answer should be

```
REvaluate["source(\"path1/path2/gensys.R\")"]
```

Comment: Path seperators should be platform dependant, even in R. I first assumed you where using Windows but now I think that you work on a unixoid OS, right?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Actually, I'm using Windows... ;)

Comment: Windows *usually* supports both `\ ` and `/` as a path separator.  To write `\ ` in an R string, one needs to escape it as `"\\"`.  You are writing an R string inside of a Mathematica string, which needs even more escaping.  Now it would look like `"\"\\\\\""`. Alternatively, you can use single quotes for R strings, which would make this `"'\\\\'"`.

Comment: I believe @Henrik is right, and the path separator depends on the OS, not on the language.  The behaviour you observe is due to the need to escape in R fist, then to escape in Mathematica a second time.  Of course, the most practical solution is to use `/` as a path separator (even on Windows) and to use single quotes for R strings.

Comment: @Szabolcs Double escaping? Oo  Good point! Btw., this might be helpful if one has to this often: `StringReplace[
 ToString[source["path\gensys.R "], InputForm],
 {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")"}
 ]`

Comment: @Szabolcs by the way, What's preferable, to define the input variables of the gensys function in mathematica, and then run the  gensys function from R, or define the data in R input and then run the REvaluate ?